# Website shows white space on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, whitespace

When I open my website on an iPhone 6plus, it looks great. Anything below that I see this annoying white space on the right side.

I'm also using skeleton.css and bootstrap.

Comment: Please post related minimal version of source code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: It will also help if you post a screenshot of the annoying white space.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to show this error. I can't find it on your web page.

Comment: But on the right side where is the white space?..... Even in google chrome simulation  tool, i see no unwanted white space.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean. It's the `row` in your 'about' section which causes the whitespace. Check your css: did you remove the margins on the `#about`? 
[image: with whitespace]

[image: Without whitespace]

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As it turns out, my inner elements, such as header font and image sizes, were too large. All I needed to do was shrink them.